# Tomcat request forwarding via service/connector

Tags: tomcat, request, forwarding, connector

i'm looking for a way to forward requests. I want to set the filtering rules (by URI) in my service (conf/server.xml). Is that possible? Here my example service:

```
<Service name="indexbuilder">
    <Connector acceptCount="100" connectionTimeout="20000"
        disableUploadTimeout="true" enableLookups="false" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
        maxSpareThreads="75" maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" port="8282"
        redirectPort="8443" />
    <Engine defaultHost="localhost" name="indexbuilder">
        <Host autoDeploy="true" name="localhost" unpackWARs="true"
            xmlNamespaceAware="false" xmlValidation="false" appBase="indexbuilder">
        </Host>
    </Engine>
</Service>
```

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1121858/redirect-all-requests-for-a-subdirectory-in-tomcat-6-0